# How can I organize the outliner with groups?

Tags: interface, groups

When I learned the basics of Maya awhile back, they taught us that we could organize and clean the outliner window with groups. Anyway, it doesn't seem that I can hide multiple objects into one grouping in the Outliner in Blender.

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: If you'd like to have groups directly in the "All Scenes" outliner, see [this proposal](https://rightclickselect.com/p/ui/Xjbbbc/display-groups-in-outliner-all-scenes) and upvote it if you agree (that doesn't mean it will happen but more votes=more chances)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Basically you can use [Groups and Parenting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/parents.html) to organize your scene.

- Grouped objects are displayed hierarchically in the group view.

[image]

- Parented objects would be displayed hierarchically in the outliner's default view.

[image]

See the [Outliner Documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/outliner.html) for more detailed information.

Comment: I found the "add to group" under the Object's "Object: Object" property pane.

Comment: It is also possible to use layers to organize complex scenes