# Selecting groups in blender

Tags: groups

How do I select groups? I don't want to select an object and then its siblings, but I want to see a list of groups and I want to select a group like that. Is that possible?

The reason I don't want to select an object and then its siblings is because it also selects objects I previously removed from the group.

Comment: You can select object by group only by selecting object and then Shift+G > Group. Or you can set outliner to show only groups by choosing that from its list and selecting group by clikcing on its name in Outliner. So what do you want to select? Also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105/is-it-possible-to-group-several-objects-and-then-manipulate-them-scale-rotate

Comment: Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/how-can-i-organize-the-outliner-with-groups and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7207/can-i-group-items-only-in-the-outliner

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea why Shift+G > Siblings selects objects I previously removed from the group (and when I check its properties, that object is not a member of any group).

Comment: Select Similar > Siblings isn't expected to select by group, it selects  object with one parent (or without any parents at all)

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47295/sketchup-like-components-case-study-is-it-in-or-even-feasible

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can  use the outliner to choose groups and then hit the + to select the object in the group.

[image]

One of the best settings I ever changed in Blender was having a double RT Click automatically select the group. No need to Shift + G or anything.

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer! I wanted to know a way to select multiple groups at once. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome tip, this should be added as standard shortcut.